# Change class object in Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I feel like I am missing something very simple but still cannot figure out how to achieve the result after reading docs of the multiprocessing package. **All I want is to set a class object (property) in a separate process and return it back to the main process**. What I tried:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr = 'hello'

def worker(queue):
    b = B()
    setattr(b.__class__, 'prop', property(lambda b: b.attr))
    assert b.prop
    queue.put(b)

queue = Queue()
p = Process(target=worker, args=(queue,))
p.start()
res = queue.get()
p.join()

assert hasattr(res, 'prop')
```

So property "prop" just disappears. What is the proper way to return it ? I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Processes do not share state. This is pretty clearly documented in the multiprocessing docs.

Comment: Isn`t Queue designed to share objects between processes ?
https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes

Comment: You aren't passing *the class* you are passing *the instance*. The instance is pickled, sent across the wire, and then unpickled. The instance now is using the class from the original process, not the subprocess

Comment: are you suggesting to pass B together with b then ?

Comment: No, that wouldn't be my suggestion, I don't even think that would work. I would *suggest* an alternative way of accomplishing whatever it is you are ultimately trying to accomplish, one that doesn't rely on shared, mutable state.